# Apache web server and redirection of root context

Tags: apache

I am using Jboss 7.1 and Mod Cluster 1.1.
I have set up a cluster with 2 node.Here is a brief description of the setup.

1) Host 1 : Acts as a Load balancer (Apache HTTPD + Mod_Cluster). The same machine has a shared DB for cluster.
2) Host 2 : Pure application server node.JBoss
3) Host 3 : Pure application server node.JBoss

I have 3 applications(2 EARs + 1 WAR) installed on each of the app server nodes.The war file is deployed at the root context.
If I connect to individual app servers (e.g. "http://host2:8080/"), I do get to the home page of the application.
However, If I connect to load balancer node ("http://host1:8080/"), I do not get to the homepage of my application, instead I get the default index.html page of Apache.

Can I force apache to redirect it's root context to an application deployed on the selected worker node ? Please remember that the applicaton to which I want to redirect is also deployed at the root context in JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

the root context is excluded by default:

```
/subsystem=modcluster/mod-cluster-config=configuration
ls
...
excluded-contexts=ROOT,invoker,jbossws,juddi,console
...
```

Note: If you remove it from the excluded-contexts, the other contexts cease to be excluded as well.